# Formatting a Python list

Tags: python, list, format

Hello I am currently scraping information from online and putting it into a list however the elements are appearing as :

```
['\n      Michael\n    ', 
'\n      Elad\n    ', 
'\n      Yair\n    ',  
'\n      Liron\n    ',  
'\n      Idan\n    ',  
'\n      Tomer\n    ',  
'\n      Ofer\n    ',  
'\n      Asaf\n    ',  
'\n      Tomer\n    ',  
'\n      Ronit\n    ',  
'\n      Guy\n    ',  
'\n      Lior\n    ']
```

Is there a way to format the list to erase the line indentations and the white space?

Thank you

Comment: `[x.strip() for x in list]`

Comment: Hello Ajejandro, used `strip()` for the `\n`, `lstrip()` for leading space and `rstrip()` for trailing spaces;
`listing = ['\n      Michael\n    ', '\n      Elad\n    ', '\n      Yair\n    ', '\n      Liron\n    ', '\n      Idan\n    ', '\n      Tomer\n    ', '\n      Ofer\n    ', '\n      Asaf\n    ', '\n      Tomer\n    ', '\n      Ronit\n    ', '\n      Guy\n    ', '\n      Lior\n    ']`
`new_list = [((item.rstrip()).lstrip()).strip('\n') for item in listing]`
`print(new_list)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.strip()` method:

```
>>> l = ['\n      Michael\n    ', '\n      Elad\n    ']
>>> l
['\n      Michael\n    ', '\n      Elad\n    ']
>>> [x.strip() for x in l]
['Michael', 'Elad']
```